# how to access django settings from 3rd party module?

Tags: python, django

i'm writing a django-agnostic module, that will be importet anywhere inside django subdir tree.

I want that if this module is imported from within any arbitrary django project, it will detect that it's running in a django environment, 
and it will find and import settings.py, from anywhere inside the project?

e.g.
\django
 \app
  \import XXX.settings ?

\django
 \project
  \somewhere
   \import XXX.settings

(I'm, looking for a general purpose solution, not in particular to a specific dir.)

Comment: Do you mean your module has it's own settings.py , or you want to access the project's settings.py?

Comment: i want it to access the project's own settings.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module should access django settings in the standard way:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

> Also note that your code should not import from either
>   `global_settings` or your own settings file. `django.conf.settings`
>   abstracts the concepts of default settings and site-specific settings;
>   it presents a single interface. It also decouples the code that uses
>   settings from the location of your settings.

If your module has it's own settings, they can be configured in the project's settings.py.  You can hard-code sensible defaults in your module, and you can raise `ImproperlyConfigured` if you require a settings.py value.